# In Orchard Version 1.7.2 Culture Picker does not work. Is there is any alternative module

Tags: orchardcms, multilingual, orchard-modules

I try to set different languages for my site but unfortunately Culture Picker module does not compatible in orchard version 1.7.2. Is any other module is there for alternative.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's inbuild culture picker in version 1.9 which should be coming out this month, but if you don't want to upgrade, this one should work on 1.7 https://gallery.orchardproject.net/List/Modules/Orchard.Module.RM.Localization

Comment: It works fine but I need to add the flags icon instead of using language name. Is there is possible to add the flag icons.

Comment: "http://www.oxfordeconomics.com/" I want exactly flag icons which using in this link.

Comment: I don't have experience with this module, but looking at source it appears that you can just override DropdownCookieCulturePicker.cshtml, copy it to your theme, change it there and restart your application. If it's changing but you don't know how to rewrite it to show flags, ask another question and include this file's code in it. It's fairly basic ASP.NET/HTML stuff.

Comment: in 1.9 goto Modules and Enable "Culture Picker"

Answer (score 0):

Use Localization module and enable the Layout Selector module.
For reference https://layoutselector.codeplex.com/documentation